# Setting state in promise, this.setState is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to set the response to my movie state. However, I keep getting the error, **_this.setState is not a function**

```
getMovie(e){ 
  //use local this
  let _this = this;
  axios.get(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=${e.value}`)
  .then((response) => {
  _this.setState({movie: response.data });
 })
 .catch((error) => {
 console.log(error);
});
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can you show the part from where you are calling `getMovie(e)` method ??

Comment: What happens when you do `console.log(_this)`?

Comment: As saadq probably wants to point out is that '_this' is not accessible from within the method, you should probably make it available through a method parameter

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies, I forgot to bind to `this`:

`this.getMovie.bind(this)`

Comment: FWIW, you don't have to use `_this` since you're using ["fat arrows"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Arrow_functions).